# Who vs Whom- Overthinking or Bad Tricks?

Tags: whom, who

I get confused about the “tricks”
we are supposed to use to figure out the right word.

“Don’t forget about the commissions you’ll be earning coming from those who you referred.”

I realize “you referred them,” so “whom“ would make sense.

But, couldn’t I also argue that “they were who you referred”? So, “who” would be correct?

Comment: The right word is _who_. You don't have to learn tricks to use it. Forget _whom_ (well, remember that it means _who_ when you see it). You won't hear it, because nobody says it unless they're reading aloud, or trying to appear intelligent and educated. But if you don't use _whom_, you won't misuse it. And at the present time, it can only be misused, because English speakers don't all use the same "rules" for using it. Many believe that it's a formal version of _who_ instead of an accusative version. Since we do have formal words but don't have accusative any more, this isn't a bad guess.

Comment: Interesting you say “unless they’re reading aloud,” because that sentence was read in a video. 

I guess what I’m asking is are both usages correct?

Comment: _Who_ is always correct (unless you pied-pipe a preposition with it, like _with whom_). That does have to be _whom_. But stranding the preposition at the end like the first sentence is better than moving it, and that's what everybody does unless they're virtue-signalling.

Comment: Wow, I never knew this! Was it always this way or is it one of those things that has recently become a thing?

Comment: It was different a century ago, and much different in 1800 (which is the conventional start of Modern English, as opposed to Early Modern English[ 1600-1800]). English syntax is a new acquisition, less than a millennium old, and it changes fast.

Comment: The technical term is that *"whom"* is *accusative* - and it follows the same rules as the distinction between *I/he/they* and *me/him/them* (the distinction for *you* has been lost). For example, the answer to the question *"who hit whom?"* would be *"he hit me"* (or *"I hit him"*). As others have said, it's considered unnecessary in modern English and *who* can always be used - I tend to use it only in writing, mainly for rhetorical emphasis.

Comment: Thanks, Steve. So, are you saying that because “you referred” is in the sentence the distinction between “who“ and “whom” is lost; therefore, “who” is fine?

Comment: @SaulGood - No, that’s not what he’s saying.  He’s saying “I/you/he/they”  and “me/you/him/them”  The distinction for ***you*** has been lost.

Comment: My advice is to ignore the whom-knockers. If you feel it's grammatically right, then use it. It's still heard quiet a lot here in the UK, where you would not be chastised for using it. In any case, there is one place where "whom" can't be replaced with "who", and that is where it is object of a preposition, as in "To whom is he talking?" Here, "whom" is obligatory.

Comment: It's true that many, many people ignore "whom". But that doesn't make it wrong to use it. I use it, and I know many people who use it here in the US, and they are not pretentious. In speaking, it's really a question of individual choice. In formal writing, however, I do see it much more often, and I'd argue that using "whom" is a more judicious choice there.

Comment: _Wrong_ and _judicious_ are judgemental terms.They don't have to do with grammar, but with social presentation. That's a different affair.

Comment: @Jim, that’s what I was saying. So, it’s the distinction for “you” that’s been lost.

Comment: @SaulGood -  It’s not clear we’re talking about the same thing.  Completely independent of the who/whom discussion.  The nominative and accusative cases for first person are distinct (I/me).  Also for third person (he/him; she/her) But they are the same for second person (you/you). It used to be (thou/thee).  Or second person plural (ye/you) But This has no bearing on the choice of who/whom.  What is similar is that (who/whom) is losing it’s distinction and becoming (who/who) - apart from the case BillJ notes, “who” is acceptable everywhere.

Answer (score 2):

As John Lawler says in his comment, "whom" can always be replaced by "who".

I would go further, and suggest that if you're saying "whom", you need to think carefully about whether that's appropriate for your audience. It's probably not.

Comment: That's not quite true. Only "whom" is possible when the pronoun is object of a preposition, as in "To **whom** am I talking?"

Comment: Yes, you're right that a one-to-one swap isn't always correct (although it often is).I really just meant that it's always able to be replaced with clearer, easier language. To use your example, "who am I talking to?" or simply "what is your name?" are more accessible ways of saying the same thing.